# MySQl: How to groupby ('year') a column with date format, ignoring month and day

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building an app with Laravel. I am using Eloquent and MySql Database. In my MySQL database I have a table EVENTS like this:

```
id  EVENT   YEAR
1   event1  2000-05-27
2   event2  2018-01-01
3   event3  2000-02-12
4   event4  2000-06-03
```

This example is just for simplicity, obviously my database has hundreds of events ocurring at any time.

The data in the column year has the 'date' format

I need to get from this MySQL table a resume of events ocurred per year. In the example would be

```
year    number of events
2000    3
2018    1
```

I did this:

```
$years = Event::groupBy('year')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*) as total, year')
                    ->get();
```

and I get this:

```
year    number of events
2000    1
2018    1
2000    1
2000    1
```

Because each date in the column is different (In the example table: 2000-02-12 !== 2000-06-03 !== 2000-05-27).

I need to group together all events happening in each year together without taking into account mont and day.

The question is:

How do I group by colum 'year' but taking into account just the year even if the events ocurred in different days and months?

Comment: By using a function, MySQL will have to go row by agonizing row to build a list of all the years. If you have a few rows in the table this won't be a big deal, but as the number of rows grows performance will start to tank. If you are using MySQL 5.7 you could create a generated column for the year and then index the generated column.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you used selectRaw, then just convert the date to year instead, so you can group like normal query.

```
$years = Event::selectRaw('count(*) as total, YEAR(year) as year')
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This solution give back the same result. It list all events one buy one asociate by year, but do not group,

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
$years = Event::selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(YEAR, '%Y') AS year, COUNT(*) AS total")
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->get();
```

`DATE_FORMAT` is more flexible than using the `YEAR()` function, and it would easily allow us to do something like group by year and month, in one column.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$event = Event::selectRaw('count(*) as yearTotal, YEAR(year) as yearName')->groupBy(\DB::raw('YEAR(year)'))->get();
```